# Variables Being Changed In Fetch But Unchanged Outside of Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I have a React App and I have an App container where I want to call a fetch to get some data to pass through to components that will need that information.

I've declared variables outside of the an onload function (where my fetch is located) and assigned them different values in the fetch. They variables will change in the fetch but outside of the fetch they remain unchanged.

How come they are not staying changed and is there a way to fix this?

I've tried changed the variables declared with var instead of let and I've tried putting the function inside the const.

I've also tried putting the fetch inside of other components (like Table as seen below) but then I have to declare two states and call a fetch withint a fetch because I'm already calling another fetch there and it becomes cumbersome...

```
let latestRelease = 0;
let draftRelease = 0;
let doClone = false;

function onload() {

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
      {
        if(result[i].id > latestRelease && result[i].status === "released") {
          latestRelease = result[i].id;
        }

        if(result[i].id > draftRelease && result[i].status === "draft") {
          draftRelease = result[i].id;
        }
      }

      if(latestRelease > draftRelease) {
        doClone = true;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
onload()
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container fixed>
        <PersistentDrawerLeft/>
        {console.log(latestRelease)} //displays 0
                <Title/>
          <Table />
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm expecting for latestRelease and draftRelease to not stay as 0 but anything greater than that but the output is just 0. With the correct values returned I'd then like to pass them as props to the components.

Many thanks!

Comment: What's calling your `onload` function?

Comment: @ZaidCrouch Ah! Nothing so far, but if I call it before return() it doesn't change the output of console.log(latestRelease)

Answer (score 2):

Part of the issue is that you don't seem to be properly distinguishing between synchronous and asynchronous code. `fetch` is asynchronous, meaning that that code is not guaranteed to run before anything else in the file. (`fetch` uses JS promises to manage async data, so it helps to have a good grasp on [using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).)

In a typical React case, you want to do a few things differently. First, you want to use component state to hold on to the data, rather than just random variables (this allows React to re-render when those values change). Secondly, when you're fetching data asynchronously, you need to work out what your app should do before the fetch is complete.

Here's a very basic example showing how this could work:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const App = ({ url }) => {
  // We'll use this variable to store an object with the details
  const [releaseDetails, setReleaseDetails] = useState(null)

  // When the component is loaded, we'll fetch the url (coming from the component props) and then
  // run your logic.
  useEffect(() => {
    let latestRelease = 0;
    let draftRelease = 0;
    let doClone = false;

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          if(result[i].id > latestRelease && result[i].status === "released") {
            latestRelease = result[i].id;
          }

          if(result[i].id > draftRelease && result[i].status === "draft") {
            draftRelease = result[i].id;
          }
        }

        if(latestRelease > draftRelease) {
          doClone = true;
        }

        // To make these details available to the component, we'll bundle them into an object
        // and update the component's state:
        setReleaseDetails({
          latestRelease,
          draftRelease,
          doClone
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // You'd ideally want some proper error handling here
        console.log(error)
      });
  }, []) // pass an empty array so this is only run when the component is first rendered

  // Because we're getting the data asynchronously, we need to display something while we wait
  if(releaseDetails === null) {
    return "loading..."
  }

  // Once the data is available, you can then use the details when rendering. You could instead
  // render a child component and pass the values as props to it.
  return (
    `LatestRelease: ${releaseDetails.latestRelease}`
  )
}
```

Speaking generally, there are probably a few React and general JS concepts you'll want to make sure you have your around, particularly around state and async data fetching. Not sure how much experience you've had with it so far, but you may want to take a look at some intro tutorials (possibly like [this official one](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)) to see how much you can follow and if there's anything that jumps out as something you need to familiarise yourself with more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Zaid! Unfortunately I've kind of just had to learn on the fly and use things without fully understanding how they work. Even if I don't want to display the data I'm fetching, I still have to store them in a state and if they change React still has to re-render?

Comment: Just to be clear, re-rendering is something you want to happen, as it's how React updates to display any changes to it's data (the prime case here being when the fetch completes and the data is available). The question isn't so much if you want to display the data or not, it's if you want your app to do something with that data -- whether than be displaying it on screen or passing it as a prop to a child component. As soon as you do want to use that data, and it's something that can change (even from unfetched to fetched), you'll need some sort of state

Comment: Ah, okay! That makes it a lot clearer, thank you. However using your code and still rendering the child components I have in return comes up with a "'latestRelease' does not exist in type '(prevState: null) => null'." error? Which I believe has to do with the const variable declared at the beginning. Can the null value be changed to any?

Comment: Sorry, should have specifically mentioned that my answer was js and not typescript. It may need some tweaks to get working proper (and that does look to be a ts error), but I'm not as familiar so can't give you a good answer to that sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with state variable ,because if state variable changes the render will call again, here your using a normal variable may be its changing but its not rendering.

Thank You.

Comment: Hi ND NAVEEN, do you mean this? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html I don't want to display the details that I'm getting from the fetch so do I still need to state variable?

Comment: yes myrmidon999 , state variable has feature that when you change the state variable it automatically call the return in funcitonal component or render in call component .

Answer (score 0):

Variable should be in the state for re rendering